# Как распарсить вывод терминала

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, консоль

Есть вывод программы в терминал. Нужно найти определённую строку, например, с помощью `grep` и считать `n` строк после до тех пор, пока не встретится пустая строка.

Вопрос в том, можно ли реализовать это с помощью регулярных выражений, и если да, то какие можно тут использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это легко делается с помощью того же `awk`

допустим имеем такой текстовый набор:

```
a aa aaa aaaa
b bb bbb bbbb
c cc ccc cccc
d dd ddd dddd

e ee eee eeee
```

необходимо вывести строки из диапазона, где первая строка содержит подстроку "**ccc**" а последняя строка это первая пустая строка после найденной подстроки, включительно.

```
... | awk '/ccc/,/^$/'
```

в результате получим

```
c cc ccc cccc
d dd ddd dddd
⁠
```